Issue with sending JSON Array in multipart/form-data from POSTMAN
I've been struggling with writable serialises in DRF and I keep having this issue:
"music_preferences": [
"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."
],
"artists": [
"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list."
]
I'm building an endpoint that is supposed to allow an admin to create an event. This is the serializer:
class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    music_preferences = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Music.objects.all(), many=True, write_only=True)
    artists = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Artist.objects.all(), many=True, write_only=True)
    event_picture = serializers.ImageField(required=False)  
# Made optional

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = (
            'name',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'venue',
            'minimum_age',
            'vibe',
            'public_type',
            'dresscode',
            'music_preferences',
            'event_picture',
            'artists',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        music_preferences_data = validated_data.pop('music_preferences')
        artists = validated_data.pop('artists')

        
# Check if event_picture is provided, else use the venue's image
        if 'event_picture' not in validated_data or not validated_data['event_picture']:
            venue = validated_data['venue']
            validated_data['event_picture'] = venue.venue_picture  
# Use venue_picture from the venue

        event = Event.objects.create(**validated_data)

        
# Set music preferences
        event.music_preferences.set(music_preferences_data)
        event.artists.set(artists)
        
        return event

This is the view in which it is invoked:
def post(self, request, venue_id):
        data = request.data.copy()

        
# Add files to the data dictionary
        if 'event_picture' in request.FILES:
            data["event_picture"] = request.FILES["event_picture"]

        
        data['music_preferences'] = json.loads(data['music_preferences'])
        data['artists'] = json.loads(data['artists'])
        
        serializer = EventCreateSerializer(data=data)
        
        if serializer.is_valid():
            event = serializer.save()
            event_data = EventCreateSerializer(event).data
            event_data['id'] = 
            return Response({
                'data': event_data
            }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        
        
# Log serializer errors
        print("Serializer Errors:", serializer.errors, serializer.error_messages)
        
        return Response({
            'error': serializer.errors
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)event.id

And this is what I'm sending through POSTMAN:
My POSTMAN form-data
When I pass it with raw json, it works, tho:
{
    "name": "EXAMPLE",
    "start_date": "2024-09-01T23:59:00Z",
    "end_date": "2024-09-02T05:00:00Z",
    "venue": 1,
    "minimum_age": 18,
    "dresscode": "Casual",
    "music_preferences": "[1, 2]",
    "artists": "[2]",
    "public_type": "Anyone",
    "vibe": "Fun"
}

I've tried formatting the arrays of PKS in all different ways (["1","2"], "[1,2]",etc) in the form-data, and, I need to submit this request through multi-part because I need to allow of photo uploads.
I also added some prints to debug, and everything seems to be working. After getting the json arrays I'm using json.loads to convert them to python arrays and it is in fact working...
UNPROCESSED DATA:
––––––
<QueryDict: {'name': ['Example'], 'start_date': ['2024-09-01T23:59:00Z'], 'end_date': ['2024-09-02T05:00:00Z'], 'venue': ['1'], 'minimum_age': ['18'], 'dresscode': ['Casual'], 'music_preferences': [[1, 2]], 'artists': [[2]], 'public_type': ['Anyone'], 'vibe': ['Fun']}>
––––––
MUSIC_PREFERENCE DATA AFTER LOADS
––––––
[1, 2]
––––––
ARTISTS DATA AFTER LOADS
––––––
[2]
––––––
I've been researching a lot and haven't found a lot of information on this issue—writable "nested" serializers seem to be pretty complicated in Django.
If anyone has any idea it would help a lot!

With form data your keys need to be like music_preferences[0], music_preferences[1], artists[0] for lists.
